# How do you associate an Azure web app with a vnet using PowerShell Az?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I know it can be done using Azure CLI like this:

```
az webapp vnet-integration add -g $resourceGroupName -n $applicationName --vnet $vnetName --subnet $subnetName
```

Is there an equivalent command using [PowerShell Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.3.0)?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this David?  I'm trying to put together a Powershell script to clone a web app and then set up its vnet integration - was trying to avoid mixing Azure Powershell and Azure CLI commands if possible.

Comment: I just moved on. Looking at the docs, it looks like they've added a generic way to use  `New-AzResource` which wasn't there when I originally looked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet, at the bottom is a link to the Script Center gallery where this is a full PS1 script at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-an-app-in-Azure-ab7527e3 which shows how to integrate web app with vnet.

The final lines of interest (it uses AzureRM, but should be easy to convert to Az):

```
$PropertiesObject = @{
"vnetName" = $VirtualNetworkName; "vpnPackageUri" = $packageUri
}

New-AzureRmResource -Location $location -Properties $PropertiesObject -ResourceName "$($webAppName)/$($vnetName)/primary" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections/gateways" -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -ResourceGroupName $webAppResourceGroup -Force
```

Comment: I did follow that link and attempted many variations of conversion of the AzureRM commandlets. At best, I was able to get a vnet with the gateway requirement created which is _not_ what I want/need. I want to emulate the Preview functionality that the portal provides which is what the CLI command does in my question. Unfortunately, this does not answer my question which explicitly requests how to generate the exact same result as the CLI command using Az.